# Subjunctive or indicative: "was" or "were" after he

Tags: grammaticality, subjunctive-mood

I have a question regarding which it should be:

> He acted as if he **were** owner of the place

or

> He acted as if he **was** owner of the place.

Which is correct?

Comment: Alternative that flows better: "as if he owned the place".

Comment: @PixelSnader Yes I like that phrasing better too.  I generally approve of the strategy of re-working a sentence to avoid awkward artefacts of ancient grammar rules.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative that flows better: "as if he owned the place".

Not what you asked, but I figured I'd mention it anyhow.

Comment: You should post this as a comment, as it is not an answer to the OP's question.

Answer (score -1):

The correct phrase is:

> He acted as if he were the owner of the place.

This is a great example of the [subjunctive in English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive#Compound_forms.2C_auxiliaries_and_modals), which is used to express ideas that are contrary to fact.

It is also a great example of formal "correct" English diverging from common parlance.   Many people say "as if he **was** the owner of the place" in casual speech.

Comment: Sorry, but that's just not accurate :( In about three ways.